# Format string exploit, printing variables from stack

Tags: c, string, stack, format

I'm learning about format string vulnerabilities, and I've written a test program to try them out on. This is my test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char test[] = "Whatever \n";
printf(argv[1]);
return 0;
}
```

If I use `%p` as `argv[1]`, it of course prints out an address from the stack. If I enter `%s`
as `argv[1]`, it prints out:

```
__libc_start_main
```

Am I doing something wrong with my program, or my arguments? How can I have it print the `test[]` array from the stack? This is just an example, I want to know how to print out any variable in general from the stack. I was just using this program so I'd have an easy example.

Comment: What operating system and compiler are you using?  You need to add tags for that.  And is this homework?  If so, please add that tag.

Comment: I trust you're aware that your code's behavior is undefined (i.e., not defined by the C standard).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C language scanf copies extra string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709508/c-language-scanf-copies-extra-string)

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers might optimize out the definition of test[], which doesn't appear anywhere else in your function. Try using the array elsewhere in main.

Answer (score 1):

test[] isn't going to be on the top of the stack within printf.  It will be somewhere below argv[1] and the return address, so your code as written will never work.  If there's a way to get it to work at all, you're going to have to give it more than one format specifier for argv[1].  You're going to need to familiarize yourself with C calling conventions, the stack, and a bit of assembly to solve this one.

Comment: Okay, what about this code. I've followed a video tutorial which used this code, and it worked perfectly in the video but the same problem is occurring for me:                                #include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *poop = "test";
printf(argv[1]);
return 0;
}