# C language scanf copies extra string

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char x[5];
    char y[10];
    scanf("%s",x);
    scanf("%s",y);
    printf("%s %s",x,y);
}
```

I typed "hello world" in the terminal, but the printf result is "helloworld world".
Is there something wrong I'm doing?

Comment: I'm still curious as to why it didn't just terminate after the second "l"
Like printing "hell" (yeah this wasn't intentional)

Comment: Because it is *undefined behavior*. There's no meaningful "why" here. Anything can happen. And I don't see any reason why it would terminate "after the second l"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in C are terminated by a null byte.  So the string "hello" actually needs 6 bytes to store: 5 for the letters in "hello" and one for the null byte.

The variable `x` is only 5 bytes wide, so it's not big enough to store the string "hello".  As a result, attempting to write this string to `x` writes past the end of the array.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as writing to an adjacent variable.

Increase the size of `x` to prevent overrunning the array.  You should also use a field width in the format specifier to specify the maximum number of characters to read:

```
char x[6];
char y[10];
scanf("%5s",x);
scanf("%9s",y);
```

Answer (score 2):

Never, never, really never use the `"%s"` format specifier without a WIDTH to tell `scanf()` how many characters it may put into the memory pointed to by the argument.

```
char str[5];
scanf("%4s", str);
```

Comment: How often does it make sense to use scanf for strings, even with the width specifier?

Comment: @supercat 2 to 3 times a year.

Comment: How do you ensure sensible behaviors in cases where an input line might or might not contain whitespace characters?

Comment: @supercat By not using `scanf()` in such cases.

Comment: In what cases would it be appropriate for a program to behave nonsensically if the number of whitespace characters received doesn't match expectations?

Comment: @supercat I am not sure i am following you.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare

```
char x[5];
char y[10];
```

In memory, you have something like:

```
                     1 1 1 1 1 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 
+---------+-------------------+
|. . . . .|. . . . . . . . . .| 
+---------+-------------------+
 ^         ^
 \-- x     \-- y
```

After the first `scanf`, you write `hello\0` in `x`

```
                     1 1 1 1 1 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 
+---------+-------------------+
|h e l l o|0 . . . . . . . . .| 
+---------+-------------------+
```

After the second `scanf`, you write `world\0` in `y`

```
                     1 1 1 1 1 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 
+---------+-------------------+
|h e l l o|w o r l d 0 . . . .| 
+---------+-------------------+
```

When you type `printf("%s", x);` you ask to type to write from `x` to
the first `\0`, so `"helloworld"` is printed.

When you type `printf("%s", y);` you ask to type to write from `y` to
the first `\0`, so `"world"` is printed.

*Note:*

The memory arrangement is not deterministic, you should have all kind of other results, even crashes...

You can find a good tutorial to use `scanf` here: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html